# A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'. > Could not find method classpath()

Tags: flutter, dart, android-gradle-plugin

This is the error that occurred.

[image]

This is the build.gradle file

[image]

Help me o fix this error.I tried many ways but none of them worked for me.

Build file 'D:\THE WALL\thewall\android\build.gradle' line: 7

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.154] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s